# sqlite create/delete lots of tables

Tags: database, transactions, sqlite

I am using sqlite in multithreaded process. I have both in-memory db and filesystem db attached together. I have a requirement to keep moving tables from in-memory db to filesystem db(move 2 tables across every 5 sec). Also keep deleting older set of tables in both the DBs(around 5 tables in every 5 sec).
I am wondering what should be the best design approach to get maximum performance?

At certain times I am noticing database being locked for over 2second. There are around 400 tables in each db but the tables are mostly 2 rows in size. I am using begin immediate transaction type for every operation.

Comment: 400 tables? Do any of these have the same schema?

Comment: Without knowing more about your requirements, I have to wonder if your starting from a good premise. When you have 400 tables with 2 rows each, are these really 400 distinct entities that each require their own table, or are you creating multiple tables to divide your data into subsets when you could just add a column to the table to identify the subset. For example, separate table for each customer instead of having a customer field. Adding records to an existing table is a whole lot faster than creating a new table.